# Interfaces and contracts in ethereum

Tags: interface, token, ethereum, smartcontracts

I've seen this asked before but I still need some clarification on where exactly the functions declared in an interface are fully defined? I understand the interface lays out and explains functions that another contract (contractB) can use but is the interface just a convenience and not a necessity for contractB to use those functions? In my mind I'm confusing delegateCall with interfaces. If we want to call functions from other contracts, why use interfaces rather than delegateCall? If the contract address pointed to by the interface has a function defined but I do not outline it in the interface, can I still use it in contractB?

For example, below I know I can use transfer function in crowdsale but where is transfer? Let's say contract A has function makepovertyhistory() defined but I do not mention it in the interface token...can I still use it in the crowdsale contract?

If I redefine the transfer function inside the interface, does it overwrite the transfer function defined at the address instantiated within crowd sale contract? I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this all correctly so thought I would ask more detailed questions in case anyone else found the generic answers still to general to build a visual of what's going on.

It might be helpful to also distinguish why we would use an interface instead of inheriting a contract directly into my currently being created contract

```
interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
....
....
..
```

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces in Solidity are really no different than interfaces in any OOP. They allow you to code towards a stub without knowing the underlying implementation. If a new version of a contract that implements the interface is needed, your contract that uses it doesn't need to change.

This allows you to address one of the common problems in smart contracts: upgradable contracts. By using an interface, you can deploy a new version of a contract, then update any existing contracts with the new address.

Simplified example (obviously, this would not pass basic security checks, but you get the idea).

```
interface I {
  someMethod();
}

contract C {
  I i;

  C(address _addr) {
    i = I(_addr);
  }

  doSomething() {
    i.someMethod();
  }

  upgrade(address _newAddr) {
    i = _newAddr;
  }
}
```

Providing this type of separation (and using libraries) makes upgrading contracts much easier and cheaper.

> For example, below I know I can use transfer function in crowdsale but
>   where is transfer? Let's say contract A has function
>   makepovertyhistory() defined but I do not mention it in the interface
>   token...can I still use it in the crowdsale contract?

No, it needs to be imported or defined somewhere.

> If I redefine the transfer function inside the interface, does it
>   overwrite the transfer function defined at the address instantiated
>   within crowd sale contract?

It depends on how you're calling the transfer function. If you're executing it on the address of a deployed contract, then you are using that deployed contract's implementation.

A more in-depth example can be found in [this blog post](https://blog.colony.io/writing-upgradeable-contracts-in-solidity-6743f0eecc88).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To really hit the point home, where is someMethod() defined? It would be at a particular address of a contract that uses that interface correct? So contract A is I{someMethod()}is deployed at address 0x1111 and contract B is I{someMethod()}is deployed at address 0x2222. In C i=I(0x2222) i.someMethod() uses the contract B definition of someMethod? So interfaces don't actually do anything they just help serve as a way to group and link contracts together that use the same function names/signatures even though each contract may define them differently.

Comment: That's correct. It's needed so that the contract making the call can compile. To make things even more interesting, say you have 2 methods defined in interface I (`someMethod1`, `someMethod2`), but the calling contract is only interested in calling `someMethod2`, you can write your local version of the Interface to only have `someMethod2()` defined. The example you posted shows this because the token interface is only defining a subset of the ERC20 spec (which is where the example originates). The more likely scenario is the interface is posted somewhere and you would import it.

Comment: In addition, the contract that is called doesn't even need to be declared as implementing the interface. But, this would be pretty poor design.

Comment: Ok so when I deploy contract A I can just do contract A{} rather than contract A is I{}? And when I define the interface in my newly deployed contract it can still find the functions in contract A since I give the address of where it is on the blockchain? It would save gas to not declare large interfaces so I can see an incentive not to define them. Is this right? I think I'm grasping this but now I'm wondering why using delegateCall() on contract A from C wouldn't be better since delegateCall uses gas per call but so do interface calls right? Except interfaces also need to be defined so +gas

Comment: No, using an interface alone does not increase gas. You may be confusing interfaces with libraries. Libraries are singletons and allow your contract to use them within the context of the contract. Calls to the library use delegatecall(), which is usually cheaper in gas but also introduces security risks. For basic contract to contract calls, you can control how the call is executed. You can call _address.call(), _address.callcode(), or _address.delegatecall(). But, you're right that usually calling delegatecall() on the address will be cheaper than the method call through the interface.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!